# android apk files with strange folder structure, all files directly inside /res folder

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, proguard, android-app-bundle

normally when you open an APK file as zip, inside res folder there are multiple sub-folders named, `layouts, drawable-xx,values-xx, raw, xml,` ...
but I've seen a few APK files that have all the files stored directly inside /res folder named with two chars [0-9 A-Z] incrementing like A1, A2,..., AA. (9patch files were like BZ.9.png)

google play store version-30.7.19-21 is like this. also when I open these APK files using some APK editor/decompiler the /res subfolders and file names are viewed as normal. (resources.arsc)
how is this possible? does Kotlin or Gradle or some Obfuscator like proguard do this? 
I would like to implement this on my app.
does google play do this type of obfuscation in it's released APK files when you upload a bundle to it? or maybe some 3rd party software that converts an app bundle to apk?
note: It looks like something pro-guard does. it does rename classes to a shorter version, before compiling it into dex, MainActivity.java becomes a.class, but Im not sure.

Edit: I have tried to realease an apk with this gradle settings but I still got the standard subfolder structure. i also did android.enableD8=true, also enabled R8
in gradle.properties

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            useProguard false
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've never bothered to look, but don't apps that are uploaded as AAB get converted to specific APKs when downloaded from the store? The main point of AAB is so the Play Store can strip out all the resources that are not relevant to the device that is downloading the app.

Comment: I mean google might be using some private library or something like dexguard pro-guard to generate this kind of APKs. obviously your file names are readable for yourself and /res subfolders are still there when you generate APK or app bundle using android studio. the point is the final release of the apk doesn't have any subfolders inside /res, and all resource files are there inside one folder "/res" with 2Letter names.  @Tenfour04